# How Invoke python class using metaclass and command line

Tags: python, metaclass

At this moment I have sth like this:

```py
from abc import ABCMeta, abstrachmethod

class MainClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):
  def __init__(self, args):
    print(work)

  def do(self):
    print("Do")

  @abstractmethod
    def todo(self):
      "comment"

class A(MainClass):
  def __init__(self,args):
    super(MainClass,self).__init__()

  def todo(self):
    print("nanananananana batman!")

class B(MainClass):
  def __init__(self,args):
    super(MainClass,self).__init__()

  def todo(self):
    print("Spaghetti code!")
    self.do()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-variable", default=1)
    parser.add_argument("-because",default="non important")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.variable == 1:
       foo = A(args)
       foo.todo()
    elif args.variable == 2:
       foo = B(args)
       foo.todo()
```

Is better way for invoke this class, depend from command line? I think about pattern strategy but I am not sure how implemented this in.
In future I will be have more class.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract Base Classes are meant to clarify the semantics of classes and methods in a large code base, and serve as  a little more than a runtime enforced "comment" in the base class, that certain methods must be implemented in derived classes.

Given your code sample, it seems you are still learning to use `class` and related constructs in Python and programming in general. It is safe to say that using abc or ABCMeta is **not needed** by your code, and that you can come back to them when you've got a firm grasp of how classes and objects work.

Just leave all of it out - and write your code without any import from `abc`, no `@abstractmethod` decorators, and no `metaclass=` declarations at this point - you probably saw those in some example code you are following, but they will do no good at this stage.

All that said, the code above would be broken (if you fixed the indentation syntax, which makes it instantly even more broken) - the idea of an `@abstractmethod` is exactly that no abstract methods should exist in a class when it is instantiated. It is used solely to mark, on the baseclass, the methods that *must* be rewritten (overiden) in derived classes. So your classes "A" and "B" should not have the  `todo` method decorated as "abstract" were this to run.

Also, you are making a call from your `B.todo` method to itself, in a straightforward infinite recursion loop, when you do `self.todo()` inside it. The correct pattern should be `super().todo()`.

Comment: Oh. Sorry, i made a little typos when I rewriten code. I fixed this, now should be correct. I still don't have answer for my question - how avoid using: ```if args.variable==1:```

Comment: As for creating the instances based on the argument passed, if you are always passing `args` and using the objects in the same way, you can only select the class to use inside the condition: `if args.variable == 1: cls=B`, and outside the `if/elif` body add `foo = cls(args); foo.todo()`. If you don't want an `if/elif` at all in this case you can use a dicionary mapping the arg value to the desired classes: 
`config = {1: A, 2: B}; foo = config[args.value](args); foo.todo()`